# Перехват, и управление событиями мыши в системе

Tags: delphi

Реально ли перехватить, и управлять всеми событиями мыши в системе?
**Цель**: исправить неправильную работу колеса мыши.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю реально. Когда-то фиксил у мышки проблему двойного клика из-за износившегося переключателя и дребезга контактов.

```
program MouseClickFix;

uses
  Windows,
  Classes,
  SysUtils,
  Messages;

var
  mHook: HHook = 0;
  gLastTime: DWORD = 0;

type
  TMSLLHOOKSTRUCT = packed record
    pt          : TPoint;
    mouseData   : DWord;
    flags       : DWord;
    time        : DWord;
    dwExtraInfo : PDWord;
  end;
  PMSLLHOOKSTRUCT = ^TMSLLHOOKSTRUCT;

const
  THRESHOLD = 40;

function LowLevelMouseProc(nCode: Integer; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): Longint; stdcall;
var
  VBlock: Boolean;
  VHookStruct: PMSLLHOOKSTRUCT;
  VCurrentTime: DWORD;
  VElapsedTime: DWORD;
begin
  if nCode < 0 then begin
    Result := CallNextHookEx(mHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    Exit;
  end;

  VBlock := False;

  if nCode = HC_ACTION then begin
    VHookStruct := PMSLLHOOKSTRUCT(lParam);
    VCurrentTime := VHookStruct.time;
    VElapsedTime := VCurrentTime - gLastTime;

    if wParam = WM_LBUTTONDOWN then begin
      if VElapsedTime < THRESHOLD then begin
        VBlock := True;
      end;
    end else if wParam = WM_LBUTTONUP then begin
      glastTime := VCurrentTime;
    end;
  end;

  if VBlock then begin
    Result := 1;
  end else begin
    Result := CallNextHookEx(mHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
  end;
end;

const
  WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;

var
  VMsg: TMsg;
begin
  mHook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, @LowLevelMouseProc, hInstance, 0);

  while GetMessage(VMsg, 0, 0, 0) do begin
    TranslateMessage(VMsg);
    DispatchMessage(VMsg);
  end;

  UnhookWindowsHookEx(mHook);
end.
```

Делается установкой глобального хука при помощи [SetWindowsHookEx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa) и обработки событий [WH_MOUSE_LL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644986(v=vs.85)). Судя по тому, что в списке событий, на который срабатывает обработчик есть события WM_MOUSEWHEEL и WM_MOUSEHWHEEL можно и с колёсиком что-то сделать.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.

Comment: Перехватывать всё получается, а вот управлять ни в какую... вот как например инвентировать прокрутку? (скролл вверх = скролл вниз, скролл вниз = скролл вверх)

Comment: @LEGENDED Лучше задайте новый вопрос с описанием конкретной проблемы. Ведь если не получается, значит что-то делаете неправильно. Вот и опишите что делаете. Могу подсказать только что, теоретически, при обработке сообщения [WM_MOUSEWHEEL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-mousewheel) нужно изменить знак у WHEEL_DELTA на противоположный и передать изменённое значение дальше по цепочке хуков в CallNextHookEx.

Comment: То есть можно передавать свои значения по цепочке тем самым управляя событиями?

Comment: @LEGENDED Естественно.